# Upload user profile image from custom plugin controller

Tags: form, image

Im trying to upload a profile image from a front end form via a controller function

this is what i have but the $image keeps returning null?

```
<form name="updateProfile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="hidden" name="action" value="salesforce/saveContact">
     <input type="file" name="photo" id="avatarUpload">
     <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

and my controller action is

```
public function actionSaveContact()
{

    $this->requirePostRequest();

    $userPhoto = craft()->request->getPost('photo');

    $user = craft()->userSession->getUser();

    craft()->users->saveUserPhoto('test.jpg',$userPhoto, $user);

}
```

Not sure what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image data is not going to be in POST variable. You should be using

```
$userPhoto = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('userPhoto');
```

Comment: ahh getting closer.  how do i make that an \craft\image?  getting this error Argument 2 passed to Craft\UsersService::saveUserPhoto() must be an instance of Craft\Image, instance of CUploadedFile given

Comment: Take a look at UsersController::_processUserPhoto(). All the cropping logic there just ensures that the image is square.

Comment: hmm how would i call that from a plugin controller?  Fatal error: Call to private method Craft\UsersController::_processUserPhoto() from context 'Craft\SalesforceController'   I tried just $userPhoto = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('photo');;
    $userPhoto = UsersController::_processUserPhoto($userPhoto);

Comment: ahh nevermind i see it in there.. do user profile images have to be square?

Comment: Well, that's how they are in the CP. If you don't mind them being stretched or squeezed in the CP, you'll be fine.